# Comparing stateless widgets for equality flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, constants, statelesswidget

Im currently experimenting with flutter, and I wrote the following code.

```
Text t1 = const Text("Hi");
Text t2 = const Text("Hi");
print(t1 == t2);
```

The print statement prints false, but because i'm creating two constants, shouldn't this print true?

For example if I were to create a class with the following code...

```
 class Class1 { 
   final int? var1;
   final  int? var2;
   const Class1(this.var1, this.var2);
 }

 Class1 ob1 = const Class1(1, 10);
 Class1 ob2 = const Class1(1, 10);
 print(ob1 == ob2);
```

This prints true for the objects being equal, how are widgets different from other objects in this regard?

Comment: You're saying it's printing true and you're expecting true; so what's your question? I double checked on https://dartpad.dev , and yes, your first code snippet does print to true, as expected.

Comment: @mauriii My mistake that was a typo. I updated the first true to say false.

Comment: I copied and pasted your first snippet into https://dartpad.dev and it does prints out `true`, could you double check your results?

Comment: @mauriii I also get that it prints to true when using dartpad, however if I place the snippet anywhere in an actual flutter project it evaluates to false for some reason.